# Discord.py respond to reactions

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How would I be able to wait for a reaction and then use that reaction as a response

What I want the code to do:

User -> .buy

Bot -> "How would you like to purchase"

User -> Reacts with 1️⃣

Bot -> Says response for reaction 1️⃣

Here is my code so far:

```py
message = await ctx.send("How would you like to purchase") 
for emoji in ('0️⃣', '1️⃣', '2️⃣', '3️⃣', '4️⃣', '5️⃣'): 
    await message.add_reaction(emoji)
```

I want the bot to be able to respond to each of these reactions with different responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to wait for a response from a reaction you can try using the `on_reaction_add` event. Something like this may work:

```py
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if reaction.message.author.bot:     #checks if message is from bot
        if reaction.emoji == '0️⃣':
            #process for this reaction
        elif reaction.emoji == '1️⃣':
            #process for this reaction
        #this goes on for as many reactions you have
```

Alternatively you can use a switch instead of a block of if elif statements. You can use a switch statement like this: `switch = {'0️⃣':#process,'1️⃣':#process, #and so on}`

With this you can do:

```
switch.get(reaction.emoji)
```

This will get the process from the specific reaction in the switch statement. I hope this may be of help.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know about reaction.emoji!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but this is incase someone comes back to it in hope of help:

If you plan on using the reaction thing for just a command like a confirmation ect use [wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for) instead